# Difference between vercel.json and next.config.js for rewrites?

Tags: next.js, vercel

You can put your rewrite config in a file called [vercel.json](https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration#project-configuration/rewrites), and also the [next.config.js](https://www.google.com/search?q=next%20config%20rewrite&rlz=1C5CHFA_enAU940AU940&oq=next%20config%20rewrite&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j0i512l2j0i390j69i60l3.4214j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) file.

Is there a difference between the two, are there any advantages in using one over the other? (assuming you are hosting with Vercel)

Does one config take precedence over the other?

Answer (score 3):

With little effort, You find this:

> They are framework agnostic. You can use them with any framework on
> the Vercel platform. If you are using Next.js, it is recommended to
> continue using framework level redirects as they have precedence over
> platform level redirects.

https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration#project-configuration/redirects

In next.config.js you can generate redirects in a function:

> redirects is an async function that expects an array to be returned
> holding objects with source, destination, and...

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

Does this answer Your questions?

Answer (score 0):

The next.config.js rewrite is only applied at build time. It is an async function, so you could use it to query a content database (if you are building a static site) or use other application specific configuration files to build a list of rewrites. This could be used if you have products that are discontinued and want to redirect to a helpful page using some context instead of a 404. With a static site you won't have access to a database.

The vercel.json rewrite is applied at runtime and can make use of cookies and geolocation and more:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/dashboard",
      "missing": [
        {
          "type": "cookie",
          "key": "auth_token"
        }
      ],
      "destination": "/login"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/:path((?!uk/).*)",
      "has": [
        {
          "type": "header",
          "key": "x-vercel-ip-country",
          "value": "GB"
        }
      ],
      "destination": "/uk/:path*"
    }
  ]
}
```

next.config.js works for all next js apps regardless of how they are deployed (static, fullstack, on vercel, on gcloud etc.)

vercel.json only works for vercel deploys, but it isn't limited to Next.js apps. You can deploy apps in python, go etc.